# Using for...in chrome console nested object key value pair returns undefined

Tags: nested, google-chrome-devtools, undefined, for-in-loop

I am iterating over all the objects inside another object looking to log the value for the same single key in each of those objects. I am doing this in the chrome console looking to get image urls from a huge object that contains ~7500 objects inside (I mention this because I'm not sure if this is a programmatic issue or a console limitation).

The structure of the object is like so:

```
{ {obj1: {a:1, b:2, c:3,...}}, {obj2 {a:1, b:2, c:3,...}},... {obj7300: {a:1}, {b:2}, {c:3}} }
```

How do I iterate over the collection and console.log() just the value for key c?

I have tried half a dozen variations on

```
for (const obj in collection) {
     console.log(obj.c)
    }
```

but nothing ever gets logged. Instead I get the count of the collection and undefined on a single line.

Is this a chrome console limitation or what the heck is wrong with my syntax?

Edit: adding specific details - console.log(collection) outputs

```
{button_back: Object, button_back_corner: Object, button_cancel: Object, ... }
```

Any given object outputs

```
{name: "button_back", img: "resources/ui/button_back.png"}
```

All I want to do is log the string value for img for each object.

Comment: Run this: `Object.values(collection).map(v => v.img)`

Comment: Doesn't seem like Object.values is supported in chrome. VM7698:1 Uncaught TypeError: Object.values is not a function(…)

Comment: It is a standard JavaScript function so it is supported. The most probable explanation is that the page removed this method, which would mean that page is **really** messed up. Try not using any built-in methods: (() => { let i=0, imgs=[]; for (let k in collection) imgs[i++]=collection[k]; return imgs })()

Comment: The app _is_ **really** messed up. The console crashes constantly, it's a monolithic drain on resources, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a two-step process to make it work. I would still like to see a more elegant, one-line solution.

First, I mapped the big object to an array, then was able to log items as I originally intuited.

```
var values = Object.keys(collection).map(function(key) {
    return RSX[key];
});

for (obj in values) {
console.log(`${obj.img}`)
}
```

Comment: Since Object.keys works on that broken page you can use it in a one-liner (no console.log needed): Object.keys(collection).map(k => collection[k].img)